# How to get a full list of available packages with key word from terminal

Tags: command-line, system-installation, repository, libraries

I was wondering how to get a list of possible packages to be installed from the terminal, having written the first letters of the name of the package. In other words, I would like to decide and know specifically which is the package names and versions available to install with the actual repositories installed in my Ubuntu.
I supposed it was the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key that makes that work, but it did not work with my Ubuntu. I have Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but I think it will work with other Linux versions, as for example Xubuntu, but it is not my case.

For example with the `python` package, I knew there is a `python2` and also `python3` package with some differences between each other. So, I want to write:
`sudo apt install FIRST_PART_OF_PACKAGE_NAME`and do something else in order to see that list of possibilities.

In this case, for example, entering `sudo apt install python` in the terminal and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> should print on screen a full list of similar packages (in this case, it might be `python2`, `python3` and some other versions or libraries).

Comment: Autocomplete works with two tabs right in a row.  However, python might be a poor choice for this since there are over 6,000 installable apps in the repos that begin with `python`.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking.  There is no difference between Xubuntu's 18.04 LTS' search functions and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS'  outside of what I suspect is a different setting in bash's auto-competition in your two cases.  I also wonder if you're asking about `apt-cache search` function - but I'm unsure sorry.

Comment: `apt search python | grep -in "^python"` gives me 19596 results.

Comment: you mean [bash_completion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/261687/is-it-possible-to-configure-bash-to-autocomplete-with-one-tab-like-zsh)

Answer (score 1):

**[Aptitude](https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/aptitude/ch02s04s05.en.html) is your swiss army knife for package management.**

For example searching packages in section 'python' thats not 'installed' and starts with 'python'.

```
aptitude search '~spython!~i^python'
```

(Long verion)

```
aptitude search '?narrow(?section(python) ?not(?installed), ^python)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `sudo apt list <package-name>`?
You could also use `sudo apt list python-*`

Comment: There's no need to use `sudo` for those commands.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, the point of the question is what @TheAdmin8000 answered. Thanks a lot.

@guiverc: What I posted is because in other laptop I had with xubuntu, by pressing twice the `Tab` key, it automatically printed on screen all possible packages to install.

@Bac0n: Thanks, but that solution requires installing the aptitude package, and it is more simple and easier just one command. However I will keep in mind your advice.

Btw, I've just noticed that also @Bac0n linked the bash completion setting answer I was looking for. I had to put this in the ~/.inputrc:

> set show-all-if-ambiguous on

and optionally,

> set completion-ignore-case on

Thanks again!